# Odoo 10 - install data from a model automatically when installing a custom module

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to install the installer I wanted to know if it is possible? And how to proceed? While searching on the internet, I saw [this tutorial](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-default-data-in-odoo-module/) well presented. However, I do not see how the table will be correctly filled to a module.

Will you help me?

Thank you

Comment: This is possible by adding the file in the __manifest__

Comment: you can add `*.csv` or `*.xml` file

Comment: For me use `*.csv` file, by exporting data

Comment: to create a csv file with my data that I put in a folder of my module to declare it in my manifest?

Comment: of course yes!!!

Comment: Thank you ! I am beginner ... Is this file loaded with each module update? I just want it to be loaded once to install the module

Comment: Use export data from the interface

Comment: I try to make a csv file. I have export my datas with odoo interface. I have create a folder data and i have place my file 'import.annee.scolaire.csv' inside. But i have a error -> KeyError: u'import.annee.scolaire' why ? I have to try rename file for KeyError: 'import_annee_scolaire.csv'

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should look into the [official Odoo documentation for developers](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/data.html) for this topic. But your source and Odoo's doc aswell miss something very interesting.

You can put `record`s into a `data` node. In older versions this was necessary, but not in the newer ones. A `data` block can have one extra attribute `noupdate`, which will control updates on that data in the block.

Here an example:

```
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="my_group_1" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">My Group 1</field>
        </record>
    </data>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="my_group_2" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">My Group 2</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

That will create two new groups in Odoo with names "My Group 1" and "My Group 2". If you change both names to "Your Group 1" and "Your Group 2" and update the module/app again, only the second groups name will be changed back to "My Group 2".

How does Odoo do that? For every record you create by xml or csv, an external id will be created. This external id itself has a Odoo model, too. It's the model `ir.model.data` and its entries/records can be found under settings/technical (activate debug mode in newer version to see that). This model has a field `update`, which will be set on creation of a record of a xml or csv by default to TRUE or if you use a `data` node with `noupdate="1"` to FALSE.

And one last hint: If you delete records with noupdate option, they will be recreated on module update, because you will delete the `ir.model.data` (external id), too.